# Couchbase Sync Gateway cannot create indexes

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway

I receive an error when I try to start my sync gateway:

[INF] Successfully opened bucket sync

[INF] Set query timeouts for bucket sync to cluster:1m15s, bucket:1m15s

[INF] Initializing indexes with numReplicas: 1…

[INF] Verifying index availability for bucket sync…

[INF] Indexes ready for bucket sync.

[INF] delta_sync enabled=false with rev_max_age_seconds=86400 for database fwws-cluster-default

[INF] Created background task: “CleanAgedItems” with interval 10m0s

[INF] Created background task: “InsertPendingEntries” with interval 2.5s

[INF] Created background task: “CleanSkippedSequenceQueue” with interval 30m0s

[ERR] cbgt index creation failed: manager_api: could not create index, indexDefs.ImplVersion: “NS41LjA=” > mgr.version: 5.5.0 – base.(*CbgtContext).StartManager() at dcp_sharded.go:298

[ERR] Error opening database my_database: manager_api: could not create index, indexDefs.ImplVersion: “NS41LjA=” > mgr.version: 5.5.0 – rest.RunServer() at config.go:1028

Does anyone know what can trigger an error like this?

Comment: Have you confirmed that your index nodes (including replicas) are up and running. What is version of sync gateway

Comment: Yes, they were up and running. I am still not sure what caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve managed to fix this by deleting few documents:

```
_sync:cfgindexDefs
_sync:cfgnodeDefs-known
_sync:cfgnodeDefs-wanted
_sync:cfgplanPIndexes
_sync:cfgversion
```

After starting the syncgateway, all of the docs were recreated and the error - gone. I am not sure wether this is recommended or not(little information on the internet) but it solved the issues.